# How to display parent name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a departments table in db with id,name, and parent.The parent is the id that corresponds to the parent root.Now i have displayed the id(parent id) but i want to show the name of the department that correspond with this id.I have tried the query at the departmentcontroller ,index function but it gives me this error 
**Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'departments' (SQL: select `departments`.`id`, `departments`.`parent`, `departments`.`name` from `departments` inner join `departments` on `department`.`id` = `departments`.`parent` where `id` = parent)**

DepartmentController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use  App\Department;
use  App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DepartmentController extends Controller
{  

  public function usersdep($id)
  {
   $department = Department::with('users')->find($id);
   return view('admin.page-users')->with('users', $department->users);
  } 
   public function treeView()
  {
   $departments = Department::with('childs')->where('parent', 0)->get();  
   return view('admin.page',compact('departments'));
  } 

  public function index()
  {
    //$departments = \App\Department::all();  
    //return view('admin.department')->with('departments', $departments);
 return $departments =  DB::table('departments')
    ->join('departments', 'department.id', '=', 'departments.parent')
   ->select('departments.id','departments.parent','departments.name')->where('id','=','parent')->get();
  }
```

department.blade.php

```php
@extends ('layouts.master')

@section('title')
Department Management | Admin
@endsection
@section('content')

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New department</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        @if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
          {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
        @endif
      </div>
      <form action="/save-department" method="POST">
        {{   csrf_field() }}
        <div class="modal-body">         
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="recipient-id">
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name exampleFormControlSelect2" class="col-form-label">Parent ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose the department parent id"name="parent" id="recipient-parent">

            <select multiple class="form-control"  name="parent" id="recipient-parent">
            @foreach($departments as $department)
               <option>{{ $department->parent }}</option>
               @endforeach 
            </select>

          </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      @if (session('status'))
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        {{ session('status') }}
      </div>
      @endif
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title my-4 text-center font-weight-light"> Department Management </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <thead class=" text-primary">
              <th>Department</th>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" >Add</button>              
              <thead class=" text-primary">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Parent ID</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
              </thead>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach($departments as $department)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $department->id }}</td>  
                <td>{{ $department->name }}</td>  
                <td>{{ $department->parent }}</td> 
                <td>
                  <a href="{{  url('department-edit/'.$department->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                </td>       
                <td>
                  <form action="{{  url('department-delete/'.$department->id) }}" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                  </form>                           
                </td>               
              </tr> 
              @endforeach  
              <a href="{{  url('/page') }}" class="btn btn-success">See the Departments and Employees</a>                                                     
            </tbody>           
          </table>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  @endsection


  @section('scripts')


  @endsection
```

web.php

```php
<?php
use App\User;
use App\Department;

use App\Events\WebsocketDemoEvent;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    broadcast(new WebsocketDemoEvent('some data'));
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/page', function () {
    return view('admin.page');
});
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function  () {
    Route::get('/role-register','Admin\DashboardController@registered');
    Route::delete('/role-delete/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registerdelete');//delete user
    Route::post('/save-user', 'Admin\DashboardController@store');

    Route::get('/department', 'Admin\DepartmentController@index');
    Route::post('/save-department', 'Admin\DepartmentController@store');
    Route::get('/department-edit/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@edit');//edit department
    Route::put('/department-update/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@update');
    Route::delete('/department-delete/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@delete');//delete department  

    Route::get('/page-users/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@usersdep');//show users  


});
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/chats', 'ChatsController@index');//chats
Route::get('/messages', 'ChatsController@fetchMessages');//messages
Route::post('/messages', 'ChatsController@sendMessage');//messages

Route::get('/dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController@dbcheck');//DATABASE
Route::get('/user-edit/{id}', 'HomeController@registeredit');
Route::get('/role-edit/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registeredit');//edit user
Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registerupdate');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


Route::get('store_image', 'StoreImageController@index');
Route::post('store_image/insert_image', 'StoreImageController@insert_image');
Route::get('store_image/fetch_image/{id}', 'StoreImageController@fetch_image');
Route::get('/page',array('as'=>'jquery.treeview','uses'=>'Admin\DepartmentController@treeView'));
Route::get('/pageusers', 'Admin\DepartmentController@usersdep');
```

Department.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'departments';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

public function users()
{
   // return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    return $this->hasMany(User::class,'department','id');
}

   //category has childs
   public function childs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Department','parent','id') ;
    /*
    childs() method with hasMany relationship. 
    hasMany relationship in Laravel tell us that they have multiple childs. 
    Here I am creating relationship based on parent and each category has their parent if parent id is 0 it means it is root category.*/
}
}
```

create_departments_table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateDepartmentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('parent');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('departments');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to join the `parent_id` with `parent_root.id`. Then you will get the name of the `parent`.

Comment: i updated the question  i added join but gives me an error

Comment: in my db parent_id of departments is called parent

Comment: You have to show me the both table, otherwise, it is quite confusing. Can you show me both the tables?

Comment: @k_lear Yeah, then change them accordingly to your `DB`.

Comment: its one table departments and it has id,name,and parent.The parent corresponds with the id of the departments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208395/discussion-between-rob-and-k-learn).

Comment: Would suggest not using the DB facade on simple tasks like that, that's what you have Eloquent for. And you need to show model and migration file for us to be able to help you out.

Comment: i added the migrations and the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the correct department id.

```
public function index()
{         
     $departments =  DB::table('departments')->select('departments.*')->get();
     return view('admin.department', compact('departments'));
}
```

And view:

```
@foreach($departments as $department)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $department->id }}</td>  
    <td>{{ $department->name }}</td> 
    @foreach($departments as $parent)
        @if( $department->parent === $parent->id )
            <td>{{ $department->name }}</td>
        @endif
    @endforeach
<tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3):

> Alternative answer

#### Model

A `Department` model might be associated with one parent. To define this relationship, place a `parent` method on the model. The `parent` method should call the `hasOne` method and return its result:

```php
class Department extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'parent_id',
    ];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Department::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

#### Migration

```php
Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('departments');
});
```

#### Usage

Once the relationship has been defined, you can retrieve the `parent` :

```
$departments = Department::get();

foreach ($departments as $department) {
    if ($parent = $item->parent) {
        dd($department->name, $parent->name);
    }
    else{
        dd('This department is a parent')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define a relation in Department model

```
public function parentDepartment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent');
}
```

and in index method load it

```
public function index()
{
    $departments = Department::with('parentDepartment')->get();
}
```