# Laravel - How to get max_score of related parent of a child

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `appraisal_goal_types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_score` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

From the table, if parent_id is null then the row is a parent. Each child field will have its parent_id. The parent can have many child rows. Also, Only the parent can have value for max_score. The child will have 0 as its default for max_score

In my view blade I have a dropdown that will only be populated with the child fields.

I have written this function in my Controller

```
public function maxScore(Request $request)
{
    $data = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('max_score')->where('id', $request->id)->first();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

When a child field is selected, I want to load the max_score of its parent.

How do I complete the code in the function above to select the max_score of the parent of a requested id of the child.

Thank you.

Comment: do you have relationship setup?? if so, eager load the parent data using eloquent or make a second query here to get the parent data.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `$request->id`, is it a child id or parent id??

Comment: $request->id is child. But I need the max_score of the parent of that child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional statement to get `max_score` :

```php
public function maxScore(Request $request)
{
    $item                = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->find($request->id) or abort(404);
    $return['max_score'] = $item->parent_id == null ? $item->max_score : 0;

    return response()->json($return);
}
```

If `$request->id` is a child, and you don't have relation in model, you can use :

```php
public function maxScore(Request $request)
{
    $child  = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->find($request->id) or abort(404);
    $parent = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('max_score')->find($child->parent_id);

    return response()->json($parent);
}
```

Or you can add relation method :

**Your Model**

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Model::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
}
```

Once the relationship has been defined, you can retrieve the parent :

```php
public function maxScore(Request $request)
{
    $child               = Model::find($request->id) or abort(404);
    $parent['max_score'] = $child->parent->max_score;

    return response()->json($parent);
}
```

You can see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60373514/984422

Comment: the relationship should be `return $this->hasOne(Model::class, 'parent_id', 'id');`

Answer (score 0):

so do it like this:

```
public function maxScore(Request $request)
{
    $child = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->find($request->id);
    if($child) {
        $data['child'] = $child;
        $data['parent'] = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('max_score')->find($child->parent_id);
    }

    return response()->json($data);
}
```